# I'm facing Volley Time out Error and mainThread error

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-volley

I'm trying to get data to form server in Andriod app using Volley library. My data was too large when I request to fetch data but the problem was volley time out error and I also used  RetryPolicy but the problem was the same. How can I fix it?

I have already tried RetryPolicy and AsynTask but my issue can't resolve. Can anyone tell me how to resolve this issue?
//Main Function here...

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_member);

        initiateViews();
        searchViewCategory();


    }

//initiateViews function...
    private void initiateViews() {
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.search_category_recyle_view);
        mSearchView = findViewById(R.id.searchView);
        addMember = findViewById(R.id.addMember);
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    }

    private void searchViewCategory() {
        mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {

                getData();
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
//Get Data from Server function
public void getData()
{
    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, "http://alfahd.witorbit.net/api.php?search_member=a&array=1", new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObjectresponse)
        {
            Toast.makeText(SearchMember.this, "" + response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
        {
            error.printStackTrace();
            dialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(SearchMember.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
            MY_SOCKET_TIMEOUT_MS,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    requestQueue.add(request);

}


The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
VolleyTimeOutError()
```

Comment: I think it's a server issue. If the server is down or the internet is not working properly then Volley gives this type of error

Comment: the server gives a response in 20 seconds check my URL and see the results

Comment: If you are back-end dev also please do pagination on your endpoint. If you are not back-end developer ask your devs may be they have it already. BTW your URL is working fine for me. I got data successfully in 7 secs. where are you located btw?

Comment: Oh hangon, you're making StringRequest but in my case I used `JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,...`

Comment: I also used jsonObjectRequest but not resolve this issue

Comment: @ShahrozIjaz can you share your singleton class also? and if you're using JsonObjectRequest then please update your code accordingly for others to help you out.

Comment: @Faisal bro I'm using singleton class I used only this code I share

Comment: @Faisal okay I updated my code

Comment: @ShahrozIjaz You said you are using singleton class. please share your singleton class code.

Comment: @Faisal I edited my code please check it

Comment: @Faisal I'm not using any singleton class

Comment: @Faisal bro you said used JsonObjectRequest rather then StringRequest so I tried but not solve my problem

Comment: @ShahrozIjaz how did you initialize your requestQueue? can you post that code?

Comment: @Faisal I initialized in onCreate function

Comment: Okay I'll share whole code

Comment: @Faisal checkout my code now

Comment: @Faisal can you share your code where you get data successfully  in 7s

Comment: @ShahrozIjaz whats the value of MY_SOCKET_TIMEOUT_MS?

Comment: @Faisal 20000ms

Comment: @ShahrozIjaz i can confirm your code is fine. I strongly doubt your internet now. I'll share my code anyway for you to be on right track.

Comment: @Faisal can you share your code where you resolve this problem and got data successfully

Comment: @ShahrozIjaz how did you go with my answer?

Comment: @Faisal okay I'll apply your code and check what is resopnse

Comment: @Faisal which google play services library you used in this code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, At first its strongly recommended to use Volley Singleton pattern to get most out of it. My volley singleton class is this.

```
/**
 * Created by MuhammadFaisal on 8/10/2017.
 */

public class VolleySingleton {
private static final int MAX = 2 * 1024 * 1024;
private static int MAX_SERIAL_THREAD_POOL_SIZE = 10;
private static VolleySingleton mSingletonInstance = null;
private final int MAX_CACHE_SIZE = 2 * 1024 * 1024; //2 MB
Context context = null;
private ImageLoader imageLoader;
private RequestQueue volleyRequestQueue;

private VolleySingleton(Context c)
{

    RequestQueue serialRequestQueue = prepareSerialRequestQueue(c);
    serialRequestQueue.start();
    context = c;

    volleyRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(c);
    imageLoader = new ImageLoader(volleyRequestQueue, new ImageLoader.ImageCache() {
        private LruCache<String, Bitmap> mCache = new LruCache<>((int) (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024 / 8));

        @Override
        public Bitmap getBitmap(String url)
        {
            return mCache.get(url);
        }

        @Override
        public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap)
        {
            mCache.put(url, bitmap);
        }
    });
}

public static VolleySingleton getInstance(Context context)
{
    if (mSingletonInstance == null)
    {
        mSingletonInstance = new VolleySingleton(context);
    }
    return mSingletonInstance;
}

public static RequestQueue prepareSerialRequestQueue(Context context)
{
    Cache cache = new DiskBasedCache(context.getCacheDir(), MAX);
    Network network = getNetwork();
    RequestQueue requestQueue;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN
            && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    {
        try
        {
            if (checkGooglePlayServices(context))
                ProviderInstaller.installIfNeeded(context);
        }
        catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e)
        {
            // Indicates that Google Play services is out of date, disabled, etc.
            // Prompt the user to install/update/enable Google Play services.
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.showErrorNotification(e.getConnectionStatusCode(), context);
            // Notify the SyncManager that a soft error occurred.
            //syncResult.stats.numIOExceptions++;
            return null;
        }
        catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e)
        {
            // Indicates a non-recoverable error; the ProviderInstaller is not able
            // to install an up-to-date Provider.
            // Notify the SyncManager that a hard error occurred.
            //GooglePlayServicesUtil.showErrorNotification(e.getConnectionStatusCode(), context);
            //syncResult.stats.numAuthExceptions++;
            return null;
        }

        HttpStack stack = null;
        try
        {
            stack = new HurlStack(null, new TLSSocketFactory());
        }
        catch (KeyManagementException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("Your Wrapper Class", "Could not create new stack for TLS v1.2");
            stack = new HurlStack();
        }
        catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("Your Wrapper Class", "Could not create new stack for TLS v1.2");
            stack = new HurlStack();
        }
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context, stack);
        return requestQueue;
    }
    else
        return new RequestQueue(cache, network, MAX_SERIAL_THREAD_POOL_SIZE);
}

private static Network getNetwork()
{
    HttpStack stack;
    String userAgent = "volley/0";
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 9)
    {
        stack = new HurlStack();
    }
    else
    {
        stack = null;
        //stack = new HttpClientStack(AndroidHttpClient.newInstance(userAgent));
    }
    return new BasicNetwork(stack);
}

private static boolean checkGooglePlayServices(Context con)
{
    switch (GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(con))
    {
        case ConnectionResult.SERVICE_MISSING:
            Log.d("googleError: ", Integer.toString(ConnectionResult.SERVICE_MISSING));
            //GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().getErrorDialog(SplashScreen.this,ConnectionResult.SERVICE_MISSING,0).show();
            break;
        case ConnectionResult.SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED:
            Log.d("googleError: ", Integer.toString(ConnectionResult.SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED));
            //GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().getErrorDialog(this,ConnectionResult.SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED,0).show();
            break;
        case ConnectionResult.SERVICE_DISABLED:
            Log.d("googleError: ", Integer.toString(ConnectionResult.SERVICE_DISABLED));
            //GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().getErrorDialog(this,ConnectionResult.SERVICE_DISABLED,0).show();
            break;
    }
    return true;
}

public RequestQueue getVolleyRequestQueue()
{
    if (volleyRequestQueue == null)
    {
        // getApplicationContext() is key, it keeps you from leaking the
        // Activity or BroadcastReceiver if someone passes one in.
        volleyRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context.getApplicationContext());
    }
    return volleyRequestQueue;
}

public ImageLoader getImageLoader()
{
    return imageLoader;
}
}
```

there are lots of benefits in using singleton approch and one of the main is it gives you one requestqueue to do all network requests.
Now, initialize your requestQueue like this:

```
private RequestQueue requestQueue;
if (requestQueue == null)
        requestQueue = VolleySingleton.getInstance(context).getVolleyRequestQueue();
```

you can now start doing network calls like this and just to let you know I used this same method to call your endpoint and got a response successfully.

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, "http://alfahd.witorbit.net/api.php?search_member=a&array=1", new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response)
        {
            volleyCallBack.onSuccess(response.toString());
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
        {
            JSONObject jsonObject;
            NetworkResponse networkResponse = error.networkResponse;
            if (networkResponse != null && networkResponse.data != null)
            {
                String jsonError = new String(networkResponse.data);
                if(jsonError.contains("500"))
                    createErrorDialog("Something went wrong. Try Later!","");
            }
            volleyCallBack.onFailure(error);
        }
    }) 
//        {
//            @Override
//            public byte[] getBody()
//            {
//                return jsonObject.toString().getBytes();
//            }
//
//            @Override
//            public Map<String, String> getHeaders()
//            {
//                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
//                params.put("Authorization", "Bearer " + jwt);
//                params.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
//                return params;
//            }
//        };
    jsonObjectRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
            0,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
```

Comment: I have one issue in this code TLSSocketFactory() can't find

Comment: What is TLSSocketFactory()?

Comment: I'm new in android dev so I need your help @Faisal

Comment: Hey @ShahrozIjaz sorry for not replying, I was not at office because of weekend. Did you end up solving that issue?

Comment: Hey @Faisal it's okay I can get response successfully thanks for helping me but I have another issue my response was too large so I want to save but how I didn't understand how to do it?

Comment: my response in JsonObject so I iterate the object but nothing happens they go back to an activity where they start how could I resolve this issue?

Comment: @ShahrozIjaz use Gson library to handle your response. You need to define your model classes to store the response.

Comment: which one is the best model classes or Sqlite?

Comment: Which one I used that is best for this response for storage. 1) Model Classes OR 2) Database (SQLite)

Comment: tell me which one is best in this scenario

Comment: If you have to fetch data just once (just because your API is returning same data all the time) then use SQLite and store your data and don't call API again and query your database. But if you have to fetch data again and again then go with Model  classes. because your dataset is huge and writing/reading from database is expensive.