# Timeout error on real android device with volley?

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I am beginner in android. i have a problem in volley request using `xamp server` for `request` when i use real device then it give me timeout error and added retry policy but still `timeout error`.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView serverResponse;
    private Button requestBtn;
    private String url = "http://192.168.3.104/helloworld.php";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        serverResponse = findViewById(R.id.serverResponse);
        requestBtn = findViewById(R.id.serverBtn);

        final RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        requestBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                        serverResponse.setText(response);
                        Log.e("Volley MainActivity " , response.toString());
                        requestQueue.stop();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.e("Volley MainActivity " , error.toString());
                      serverResponse.setText(error.toString());

                    }
                });
                stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                        50000,
                        3000,
                        DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT)
                );
                requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

            }
        });


    }
}
```

> E/Volley MainActivity: com.android.volley.TimeoutError

Comment: are both your devices on the same network ? your server and your device ?

Comment: ar you sure you r device can access `"http://192.168.3.104/helloworld.php`?

Comment: i agree with you @VladyslavMatviienko, probably can't access that url

Comment: see my answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57519650/im-facing-volley-time-out-error-and-mainthread-error?noredirect=1#comment101509630_57519650

Comment: yes both devices are on same network.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko no sir i try it on mob browser it can't access that url.

Comment: @Faisal bhai tnx .i try it but give new error (no connection error) this time.

Comment: then it has nothing to do with your Android code. First make your server accessible from your phone

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko sir what i can do for that ..changing in url etc or what i will do plz guide me i am new in it..thanks

Comment: only you can know what to do. It does not relate to programming. You need to make your server accessible to your mobile. Probably something missconfigured in server, or in your network, or 1000 more possible problems.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko ok sir i will reinstall the server.